# ConstrainVoilationException: can't delete or update parent row in hibernate jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities in `OneToOne` relation `Product`-->`SkuImpl`-->`SkuAvailabilityImpl`

*Product*

```
@Entity 
public class ProductImpl implements  Product {
@OneToOne(targetEntity=SkuImpl.class, cascade=   {cascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true) 
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@JoinColumn(name="DEFAULT_SKU_ID")
   protected Sku defaultSku;
//setter and getters
}
```

*SkuImpl*

```
@Entity 
public class SkuImpl implements  Sku {
@OneToOne(targetEntity=SkuAvailabilityImpl.class, cascade=   {cascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@JoinColumn(name="SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID",referencedColumnName="SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
protected SkuAvailability totalSku;
//product
@OneToOne(targetEntity=ProductImpl.class, cascade=   {cascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinColumn(name="DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID")
protected Product defaultProduct;

//setter and getters
}
```

*SkuavailabilityImpl.java*

```
@Entity 
public class SkuAvailabilityImpl implements SkuAvailability{
@OneToOne(optional=true,targetEntity=SkuImpl.class) 
@Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="SKU_ID", referencedColumnName='SKU_ID',insertable=false,updatable=false)
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
protected Sku sku;
//setter and getters
}
```

*In DAO*

```
protected EntityManager manager;
public void remove(Serializable entity){
manager.remove(entity);
manager.flush();//here getting an exception
}
```

When I insert the `Product` records are inserting in respective tables. But the problem is when I tried to delete `product` getting an excpetion

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintVoilationException:  Cannot delete or  update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ssz01b`.`blc_product`, CONSTRAINT  `FKBC3A8A84B` FOREIGN KEY (`DEFAULT_SKU_ID`) REFERENCES `blc_sku` (`SKU_ID`))
```

I googled for the solution, I found `orphanRemoval=true` can solve the problem but unfortunately it is not working for me, can anyone help how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you show your delete code. Is it the managed entitty that you are trying to delete?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu please check my updated code... using `EntityManager` to `remove` the product

Comment: why not look at the log which shows the SQL invoked and then you can work it out? This is a process known as debugging.

Comment: @NeilStockton do you mean debugging the code in eclipse or by seeing server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling merge and then remove on the `entity`

```
entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(entity));
```

Comment: thank you very much your reply, I am using JPA and deleting the product entity using `remove()` given by `EntityManager` something like this          `protected EntityManager manager; manager.remove(entity)` `entity` is loading from `service` layer,

Comment: sure am trying on it, will take time to check the result bcz we are on cloud building and deploying will take time.

Comment: same exception I did changes according to your suggestion, can please tell me why this exception will occurs?

Comment: @subburoyal This exception happens when we try to delete a row from the database but failed because this row is still referenced by other table as it has a foreign key relationship. By the way, Can you post the complete  code for these three entities.

Comment: I don't have permissions to copy paste from cloud I typed manually and posted the code where it is giving an issue.. we are using `Broadleaf Commerce` framework and doing modifications according to our need. very huge code that I can't type and post here :(

Comment: @subburoyal I mean the complete code only for **these three entities**. Also, in you `JoinColumn` annotations I don't see any `mappedBy` attribute so do you have those columns in both the ends(tables). Also if possible post the **SQLs for these three entities** as both the `name` and `referencedColumn` name has same value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107695/discussion-between-madhusudana-reddy-sunnapu-and-subbu-royal).

Answer (score 0):

Add `orphanRemoval=true` for SkuAvailability child inside SkuImpl Entitiy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, do you mean for both `SkuImpl` and `SkuAvailabilityImpl` or only for `skuImpl' @Rima

Comment: Sorry, have edited the answer. Only in SkuImpl entity for SkuAvailability attribute.